# Perl Log4perl Printing and logging at the same time in a line

Tags: perl, logging, printing, log4perl

I'm reading [this](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.34/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm) and I am confused and stuck.

Should I use `ALWAYS` or `print_portfolio('themessage')` to both print and log into a file at the same time?

What I want to do:

```
if ($logfile) {
   open (FILE, '>>', "logfile");
   print "Hello" #some code from Log4perl#;
   #prints on the display and into the logfile
}
```

instead of:

```
if ($logfile) { open (FILE, '>>', "logfile"); }
print "Hello";
if ($logfile) { print FILE "Hello"; }
```

Comment: Thanks to the person who helped edit my post to highlight the code parts. I made another edit to highlight that ALWAYS is actually code and ur name disappeared so I don't know who you are :(

Comment: If you click where it says "edited X hours ago", you'll see the revision history of your post, including the name of everyone who's edited it.

Comment: The [Log4perl FAQ](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html) answers this, in several ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use neither.

- `ALWAYS` is a log level that will always print regardless of the logging level selected. Logging levels are a way of controlling how much information is logged by the logger based on the level selected
- The `print_portfolio` subroutine is an example that doesn't really have much to do with logging to screen and file at the same time.

I believe the [Advanced configuration within Perl](https://metacpan.org/module/Log::Log4perl#Advanced-configuration-within-Perl) section has a clear example on how to set up the logger to print to screen and file at the same time:

> Here's an example on how to configure two appenders with the same
>   layout in Perl, without using a configuration file at all:
>
> ```
> ########################
> # Initialization section
> ########################
> use Log::Log4perl;
> use Log::Log4perl::Layout;
> use Log::Log4perl::Level;
>
>    # Define a category logger
> my $log = Log::Log4perl->get_logger("Foo::Bar");
>
>    # Define a layout
> my $layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout->new("[%r] %F %L %m%n");
>
>    # Define a file appender
> my $file_appender = Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
>                         "Log::Log4perl::Appender::File",
>                         name      => "filelog",
>                         filename  => "/tmp/my.log");
>
>    # Define a stdout appender
> my $stdout_appender =  Log::Log4perl::Appender->new(
>                         "Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen",
>                         name      => "screenlog",
>                         stderr    => 0);
>
>    # Have both appenders use the same layout (could be different)
> $stdout_appender->layout($layout);
> $file_appender->layout($layout);
>
> $log->add_appender($stdout_appender);
> $log->add_appender($file_appender);
> $log->level($INFO);
> ```